# PyQt5's OpenGL ES 2.0 Texture Mapping for Raspberry Pi not working

Tags: python, pyqt, raspberry-pi, opengl-es-2.0, pyqt5

I want to use PyQT5 and OpenGL to create an interactive application which should run on the Raspberry Pi Zero with Raspbian.

The first step is to display an image texture on screen, but this already fails with an error message on the Pi. (see down below)

However it is running fine when executed on my Ubuntu development machine with OpenGL 2.0 profile.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

from PIL import Image
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QColor, QSurfaceFormat, QOpenGLVersionProfile)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGridLayout, QOpenGLWidget, QWidget


class GLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):

    def __init__(self, path, width, height, parent=None):
        super(GLWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.path = path
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.texture_array = []
        self.current_texture_index = 0
        self.fps = 0

        self.elapsed = 0
        self.clearColor = QColor(Qt.black)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(self.width, self.height)

    def initializeGL(self):
        version = QOpenGLVersionProfile()
        version.setVersion(2, 0)

        self.gl = self.context().versionFunctions(version)
        self.gl.initializeOpenGLFunctions()

        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D)

        self.gl.glClearColor(self.clearColor.redF(), self.clearColor.greenF(),
                             self.clearColor.blueF(), self.clearColor.alphaF())

        img = Image.open(self.path)
        img_data = img.convert("RGBA").tobytes("raw", "RGBA")
        self.texture_array.append(self.frameToTex(img_data, self.width, self.height))

    def frameToTex(self, data, width, height):
        texture_id = self.gl.glGenTextures(1)

        self.gl.glBindTexture(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id)

        self.gl.glTexParameterf(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, self.gl.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR)
        self.gl.glTexParameterf(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, self.gl.GL_LINEAR)

        self.gl.glTexParameteri(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.gl.GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, self.gl.GL_TRUE)
        self.gl.glTexImage2D(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, self.gl.GL_RGBA, width,
                             height, 0, self.gl.GL_RGBA, self.gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                             data)

        return texture_id

    def paintGL(self):
        self.gl.glClear(self.gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | self.gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        self.gl.glMatrixMode(self.gl.GL_MODELVIEW)
        self.gl.glLoadIdentity()
        self.gl.glBindTexture(self.gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texture_array[self.current_texture_index])

        self.gl.glRotatef(-90, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

        self.gl.glBegin(self.gl.GL_QUADS)
        self.gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0)
        self.gl.glVertex2f(-1.0, -1.0)
        self.gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0)
        self.gl.glVertex2f(1.0, -1.0)
        self.gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0)
        self.gl.glVertex2f(1.0, 1.0)
        self.gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0)
        self.gl.glVertex2f(-1.0, 1.0)
        self.gl.glEnd()

    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        side = min(width, height)
        self.gl.glViewport((width - side) // 2, (height - side) // 2, side,
                           side)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        main_layout = QGridLayout()

        main_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        widget = GLWidget('images/bg.jpg', 800, 480)
        main_layout.addWidget(widget)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.currentGlWidget = widget
        self.setWindowTitle("Texture Test")

    def setCurrentGlWidget(self):
        self.currentGlWidget = self.sender()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    format = QSurfaceFormat()
    format.setDepthBufferSize(24)
    QSurfaceFormat.setDefaultFormat(format)

    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code does not work when executed on the RPI. The following error is shown:

```
$ python3 GLWidget.py 
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GLWidget.py", line 43, in initializeGL
    self.texture_array.append(self.frameToTex(img_data, self.width, self.height))
  File "GLWidget.py", line 46, in frameToTex
    texture_id = self.gl.glGenTextures(1)
TypeError: QOpenGLFunctions_ES2.glGenTextures(): not enough arguments
Abort
```

I looked up the signatures of both bindings which are these:

[QOpenGLFunctions_2_0](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/sip/_QOpenGLFunctions_2_0/qopenglfunctions_2_0.sip):

```
void glGenTextures(GLsizei n, SIP_PYOBJECT *textures /TypeHint="Union[int, Tuple[int, ...]]"/);
```

and [QOpenGLFunctions_ES2](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/sip/_QOpenGLFunctions_ES2/qopenglfunctions_es2.sip):

```
void glGenTextures(GLsizei n, SIP_PYOBJECT textures /TypeHint="Union[int, Tuple[int, ...]]"/);
```

Being unfamiliar with python-sip, I tried to use an int-array and passed it to glGenTexturesleads with no success. The array remains empty.

How is it possible to make use of the RPI OpenGL support with PyQT5 in general and also specificly showing a simple image texture?

Comment: Even if you get the `glGenTextures()` call figured out how exactly were you planning on running that fixed-function code on an ES2 context?  Does Qt have [Regal](https://github.com/p3/regal#emulation)-style fixed-function emulation built-in?

Comment: Is this code for ES2 not usable in general? How does texture mapping work with ES2?

Comment: Nope, have to use shaders in ES2, they're not optional like they are in regular OpenGL Compatibility contexts.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will look into that.